# Creating an array of objects with two fields

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, properties

I'm supposed to create an array of objects in a .NET web API project (creating them as properties).
There should be a `Country` field that is the array, and it needs to contain two fields:
`Town` which is unique and `Population` which is optional.
There should also exist a `Capital` field which refers one of the towns from the array, but is outside of the said array.

I'm really not sure how to create this array, I have tried creating a new model with such data but I believe it should all be a part of a bigger model (called `Continent`, but `Country` should be the only array of objects here. T.Hanks!

Comment: you mean a list of Continents (List<continent> each of them with a list of Countries each of them get a list of Towns?

Comment: You probably have to create a Class "Continent" with the properties you want and reefer at the class "Country" to the class Continent. Then create a List<Continent>.